# Most common combinations for these models

Tags: r

I am trying to find the most common revenue models by combination. A sample of my data looks like the following:

```
  Pay per download Free apps, with in-app purchases Advertising
1                0                                0           1
2                1                                0           0
3                0                                1           0
4                1                                0           0
5                1                                1           1
6                0                                0           1
```

I want to figure out which are the most common combinations of these models.

I have tried the following:

```
prod_m = function(x){
     x %*% t(x)
}
df %>% as.matrix() %>% prod_m(.) %>% table(.)

#output
 0  1  2 
29  6  1
```

However,  I am not entirely sure this represents the most common number of combinations.

Comment: What defines the "most common revenue models by combination".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'janitor'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     chisq.test, fisher.test

tribble(
  ~"Pay per download Free apps", ~"with in-app purchases", ~"Advertising",
  0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0,
  1, 0, 0,
  1, 1, 1,
  0, 0, 1
) |> 
  clean_names() |> 
  count(pay_per_download_free_apps, with_in_app_purchases, advertising, sort = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   pay_per_download_free_apps with_in_app_purchases advertising     n
#>                        <dbl>                 <dbl>       <dbl> <int>
#> 1                          0                     0           1     2
#> 2                          1                     0           0     2
#> 3                          0                     1           0     1
#> 4                          1                     1           1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>